# How to get the UI behavior when changing mail format to html?

Tags: vba, outlook

The behavior when I change the format of a reply mail from Plain Text using Outlook VBA is not same as when using the Format Text/Format/HTML menu.

My original outgoing mail, just after hitting the Reply button looks as follows:

[image]

If I then click the HTML button it remains exactly same [image: exactly same],

except for changing the format to HTML after which I can change the font, size etc.

But if I instead change the format in a macro using

```
...BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```

(see complete code at bottom) then

- the leading blank line gets deleted
- the mail headers get deleted
- font changes to `Times New Roman 10`

[image]

Is there a way to get the UI behavior?

The macro body is as follows:

```
Sub ChangeToTextStyle()
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objMail As MailItem
On Error Resume Next

Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objMail = objItem
        objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**

Minor problems after following Eugene's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27315069/18573):

Inserting `objMail.Save` before changing the format preserves the header and blank lines but the font changes to Times New Roman instead of Lucida Console, which is what I have set in options for composing and reading plain text mail. The original text shows up in 10pt and the cursor is at 12pt. How do I
- Change font to `Lucida Console 9.5pt` for all the text in mail?
- Change color at cursor to `wdDarkRed`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to *Save* the mail item and close the inspector window to apply the changes to the UI. Outlook doesn't reflect changes immediately in the UI. Sometimes you need to re-open the message.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Can you please help me with couple of minor issues that I have updated the question with?

Answer (score 1):

Try ExecuteMSO - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419(v=office.15).aspx

"Works on controls that are built-in buttons..."

```
Sub ChangeToTextStyleHTML()
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objMail As mailitem
On Error Resume Next

Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MessageFormatHtml")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

There are other ways but you can see MessageFormatHtml, the IdMso, as the last bit of text when you hover over the selection when adding a built-in button for the Quick Access Toolbar or a ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can just set the email into html format by replacing your code with the below:

```
Sub ChangeToTextStyle()
Dim objItem As Object

Dim objMail As MailItem
On Error Resume Next

Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objMail = objItem
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:

```
objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```